# Is there other way to set the scheme in the table_schema_objs for the Index in Llama-Index

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, large-language-model, py-langchain, llama-index

Using LLAMAINDEX I want to query my SQL Server 2014 database but I'm having this problem: SQLALCHEMY is taking the dbo scheme...

```
raise exc.NoSuchTableError(f"{owner}.{tablename}")
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: dbo.ll_computers
```

The problem is that I'm not using dbo, I have another scheme dbo_v2, here is part of my code

```
table_node_mapping = SQLTableNodeMapping(sql_database)
table_names_filter = ["ll_computers"]
table_schema_objs = [SQLTableSchema(table_name=table_name) for table_name in metadata_obj.tables.keys() if table_name in table_names_filter]

obj_index = ObjectIndex.from_objects(
    table_schema_objs,
    table_node_mapping,
    VectorStoreIndex,
)
```

And when I'm querying in this part, the error appears in the query engine saying theres no 'dbo.ll_computers in db' but I don't understand why is it searching in that scheme 'dbo' if there is declared I'm using dbo_v2

```
llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=API_KEY, model="text-davinci-003"))
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, num_output=256)

query_engine = SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine(
    sql_database,
    obj_index.as_retriever(similarity_top_k=1),
    service_context=service_context,
)
# Querying...
response = query_engine.query("How many computers in the table?")
```

And I would like to know if there is a way to set the scheme or the owner in the query engine or in the SQLDatabase instance please

I've tried this, setting the scheme dbo_v2 in metadata and the SQLDatabase instance, but hasn't works

```
metadata_obj = MetaData()
metadata_obj.reflect(engine, schema='dbo_v2')

sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine, schema='dbo_v2', metadata=metadata_obj, include_tables=["ll_computers"])
```

I'm thinking too maybe declaring the tables that the LLM probably use when querying but not sure of it

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No dude, it was kind difficult because tried many solutions and at that moment I decided to use langchain instead ):